# How to send data sensor to hosting web application

Tags: python, database, server, raspberry-pi, sensors

My project is sending data from the sensor to my web application deployed already.
I tested to get data from sensor and insert into database locally in Raspberry and work fine, but my problem i want to send the data to the web application using web service instead of database locally.
Ps:the web application with .net
How do I send the data from the Raspberry Pi to the web application and store it into the database in the server.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect? I assume that your web application already has endpoint to consume some http request to store sensor data and you have dificulty of [using requests module](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/making-http-requests-in-python), is it correct? what roadblock did you encounter?

Comment: my problem how do i create webservice inside my raspberry pi and send it to the web application